# jQuery(this).find('title').next().next().next().eq(0).text();?

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

what's the better/elegant way to do this?

```
jQuery(this).find('title').next().next().next().eq(0).text(); //THIS WORKS
```

i tried using

`jQuery(this).find('title').eq(3)  //DOESN't WORK`

but it doesnt...

Comment: Could you show us the markup?

Comment: And what error do you see with the second line of code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about `nextAll().eq(2)` ? That should be the third item. And append `.text()` afterwards. If that's not it, can you provide the markup?

Answer (score 1):

.eq() is working on the set of matched elements in the chain.  So

```
jQuery(this).find('title').eq(3)
```

is finding the 4th of a set of elements matching .find('title').

what you probably want is

```
jQuery(this).find('title').nextAll().eq(2).text()
```

Comment: Thanks for the better explanation.